# gcs fuse on two seperate instances

Tags: google-cloud-storage, ubuntu-16.04, gcsfuse

So I have two separate accounts I'm sharing a gcloud bucket between. At first I had problems getting the credentials right but eventually I just added all the email-looking accounts under the IAM on the second account to the storage buckets permissions. I gave those accounts all the roles, as I want to be able to read and write from both accounts vm instances. At this point I can mount using gcsfuse, But I can't read or write to it? I can see the filesystem, but anytime I try to copy from or to I get a input/output error?

Comment: Does each service  account, separately (unitary),  can mount the GCS fuse bucket and write and read on it ? Does the problem occur only when you use the 2 accounts on the same VM?

Comment: It's two accounts on seperate vms, one, the owner of the bucket, can gcsfuse read and write on it, the other can gcsfuse, i can see the file structure, but when I try to read or write it gives me the input/output error. just tried shutting down the bucket-owners vm and no change to the secondary vm's reading or writing. basically i just want to share my cloud storage with my brother, let him read-write- or delete files to/from my bucket.

Comment: Do you have ACL on your bucket?